# Aerospike-go-cilent: High latency and Connections stuck in CLOSE_WAIT

Tags: aerospike

I am trying to run a server written in Golang which internally calls aerospike client.

Initially after server start latencies measured from the client side of aerospike were under control but after some time latencies are getting high and not coming down.

Based on my observation during high latencies, many connections from aerospike client to aerospike server are in `close_wait` state

I am using default parameters for client policy i.e, `ConnectionQueueSize = 256` and `LimitConnectionsToQueueSize = true`

My guess is since many connections are in `close_wait` state and we are limiting connections it is waiting for connection to close and create a new one and because of that latencies are high

If that is correct, How can we close the connections faster that are in the `close_wait` state?
Otherwise, What can be the reason for this?

P.S,

1. We measured latency from aerospike server side it was under 1ms (As expected)
2. No Network congestion from aerospike server side as well as aerospike client side

Comment: How frequently do you manually close connections from the client to the server? How often do you cycle through instances of the client? I'm mentioning this because it's come up in other clients (not Go) under a couple of different situations: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/connections-stuck-in-close-wait/954/8

Comment: One of server or client must be closing the connections. If not client, it can be server. Is you load sporadic ? Aerospike server will keep reaping idle connections (default value=60 secs and configurable).

Comment: Opened as an issue with the Go client repo: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/issues/198

Answer (score 1):

Limit the number of clients, which is one of the [recommendations](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/go/usage/best_practices.html) in the Go client [overview](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/go/usage), and definitely do not close the connections rapidly.

Comment: We are creating only one client for the process, We are already following those recommendations(using default client policy), We are not closing connections at all because aerospike go client will take care of it